# Losing focus in contenteditable in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, contenteditable

I have a strange behaviour with `contenteditable` in safari. My content editable lose focus when I click on the element.

```
<h1 contenteditable="true" id="authoringTitle">Title</h1>
$('#authoringTitle').click(function(){
    $(this).text('');
})
```

As you click on it in chrome, you can edit this field right away. In safari it is loosing focus and I have to click twice. [JSFiddle is available](http://jsfiddle.net/vMqyY/1/).

I tried `$(this).focus();` `$(this).contents().focus();` `$(this).attr('contenteditable', "true").focus()` from various questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305469/1090562) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640164/1090562) but with no luck.

How can I fix it, and what is the reason for this?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the described issue using Safari on Mavericks. Also, issues like this are generally resolved by using `mousedown` with `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have this on Safari on windows (5.1) and also on ipad, iphone. You are right, mousedown fixed it. Even without prevent default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in the comment, mousedown solves the problem:

```
$('#ID').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).text('');
})
```